# Angular File Explorer In Visual Code - Index Added / Modified / Contains Emphasized Items

Tags: javascript, html, angular, visual-studio-code

I may be overthinking, but whenever something appears different, I try to get return it to the state it was. I ran `ng new` in my terminal and created a new Angular Project. However, instead of the normal off-white colors in the explorer

[image: White Text Explorer]

I am receiving a multi-color file listing

[image: Color Text Explorer]

When I hover over the (M) or (A) I receive a message saying (Modified) and (Index Added) respectively. I do not know what consequences this could have further down my project, and any help would be appreciated. I have search StackOverflow and all other sites for answers, but have come up empty!

Comment: those symbols are just the way to let you know the `git status` of the file, it won't have any effects on your project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It allows you to view git status of your project and was included in version 1.18 [update](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_18#_git-status-in-file-explorer).

If you want to disable it, go to File -> Preferences->settings.
Set:

```
git.decorations.enabled:false
```

in your user/workspace settings.

It does not have any effect in your project itself.